# search a request name in a list name

Tags: c, linux

i have write this code and it's ok!. This code search a name ,"read"  from file, in a list of params.

```
static int searchName(char* nameRead, int numberRead, const char** name_list) {
    int r = -1;
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < numberRead; j++) {
        if (strcmp(nameRead,name_list[j]) == 0) {
            r = j;
            break;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Question: if i would search a name , from name_list, in nameRead,how could i change the code?
Thank you,
Regards

Ps: this code return a index to printf the correct value! It's necessary have this as return value

EDIT1:
i have in nameRead this output

```
param1
param2
param3
param4
```

and in name_list

```
    param1
    param5
    param3
    param4
    param2
    param6
```

in my case i search a name of nameRead in in nameList, but if i would search a name from name_list in nameRead, as could i change my code?

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean. Could you show what result you want for some sample arguments?

Answer (score 1):

The variable `name` does not seem to be passed as argument and is possibly defined as global, if you intend to search for what you pass as argument in `nameRead` then you might want to use

```
if (strcmp(nameRead, name_list[j]) == 0)
```

Comment: @dawejonshonn "Fix the code" is unlikely to get you much help here. Better to show what you tried, and people can help show you what you are doing wrong.